# Getting error when trying to download from s3 using php and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, symfony

I need to download the contents of directory ABC present in s3 in AWS. When this command runs - `Storage::disk('s3')->download('ABC');`

I getting this error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse {#3295 +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#3296},
```

. I'm using Php 7.2, Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you Want to download the files you need to return a response with those files, Laravela has the `response()->download()` method for this

```
//Get all the files in de abc directory    
$files = Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('ABC');

//Creates a zip calles test.zip in your public folder
Zipper::make(public_path('test.zip'))->add($files);

//Returns the zip to the clients
return response()->download(public_path('test.zip'));
```

Comment: Thank you Marijn dk. I forgot to mention I'm running the command in a terminal. I first run the command in terminal - sudo php artisan tinker and then Storage::disk('s3')->download('ABC').